# How can I calculate $\wp(αu), α\in \Bbb{C}$, $αL⊆L$

Tags: nt.number-theory, elliptic-curves, elliptic-functions

Let $\wp(u) = \frac{1}{u^2} + \sum\limits_{\omega \in L, \omega \neq 0} \left(\frac{1}{(u-\omega)^2} - \frac{1}{\omega^2}\right)$ be a Weierstrass pe function.

My question is, how can I calculate $\wp(αu), α\in \Bbb{C}$, $αL⊆L$

If $αL=L$, the answer is easy, we can replace sum up over $L$ to sum up over $αL$, $\wp(αu)=1/α^2\wp(u)$.

So the problem is in the case of $αL\subsetneq L$. Are there some known results ?

Comment: If $α=m$ is an integer, then $\mathbb{C}/\Lambda \to \mathbb{C}/\Lambda, u\mapsto m u$ corresponds to the multiplication-by-$m$ map $[m]$ on the elliptic curve defined by $\wp,\wp'$, so the algebraic formulæ for multiplication-by-$m$ will give you $\wp(mu),\wp'(mu)$ in function of $\wp(u),\wp'(u)$ and $g_2,g_3$. I'm not sure what to say for the complex multiplication case (how to write the isogeny), but is this the sort of answer you're expecting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\alpha L$ is of finite index in $L$ so you can write $L = \cup_{i=1}^n (\alpha L + \lambda_i)$ for some $\lambda_i, n$.

If you rewrite the sum defining $\wp(\alpha u)$ as a sum over $\cup_{i=1}^n (\alpha L + \lambda_i)$ and rearrange terms (without worrying too much about convergence) you should get something like

$$\wp(\alpha u) = (1/\alpha)^2 \sum_{i=1}^n \wp(u - \lambda_i/\alpha) + c$$

for some constant $c$. As Gro-Tsen suggested, you should think in terms of isogenies of elliptic curves and this boils down to Velú's formulas.